# Printing Java shapes with a delay

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, delay, java-2d

I am trying to create a program that solves the popular Towers of Hanoi game. I have succeeded in printing the disks and pegs, but I want the disks to print with a delay. For example, I want disk 7 to print, then disk 6 to print 1 second later. I tried this by putting it to sleep, but all it does is delay the whole frame from displaying, how do I make it display the shape with a delay. I have attached my code, thanks for any help!

```
package towersofhanoi;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/*g.fillOval(60 = horizontal distance , 540= vertical distance, 400 = width, 60 = height) */

public class TowersOfHanoi extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //Print the shapes and frame
        TowersOfHanoi drawRectangle = new TowersOfHanoi();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Towers of Hanoi");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawRectangle);
        frame.setSize(1250, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color pegs = new Color (251, 129, 56);
        g.setColor(pegs);

        //peg 1
        g.fillRect(250, 300, 25, 450);
        //peg 2
        g.fillRect(600, 300, 25, 450);
        //peg 3
        g.fillRect(950, 300, 25, 450);
        //bottom
        g.fillRect(200, 700, 825, 50);
        //create a color for circles
        Color circles = new Color (176,56, 251);
        //cirle 7 (Labeled from bottom to top)
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(60, 640, 400, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(60, 640, 400, 60);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        //circle 6
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(85, 580, 350, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(85, 580, 350, 60);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        //circle 5
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(110, 520, 300, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(110, 520, 300, 60);
        //circle 4
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(135, 465, 250, 55);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(135, 465, 250, 55);
        //circle 3
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(160, 420, 200, 45);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(160, 420, 200, 45);
        //circle 2
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(185, 380, 150, 40);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(185, 380, 150, 40);
        //circle 1
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(210, 345, 100, 35);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(210, 345, 100, 35);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Thread.sleep` with Swing. That'll make your entire UI stop working. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead.

Comment: You can use the java.util.Timer.schedule method here's an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm

Comment: A swing timer might fit for this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation

- separate out drawing in paintComponent() into the 3 constitute parts, these were previously separated by sleep statements
- Use state inside the TowersOfHanoi object to control what should be drawn, I've used a simple counter
- Use javax.swing.Timer to update the counter and request a repaint.

Notes

- You cannot sleep on the UI thread. Swing is single threaded and this would stop events being processed.
- javax.swing.Timer automatically fires the callback you give it on the UI thread.
- paintComponent() can be called multiple times if windows are resized etc, therefore it is important to make it independent, hence my use of a counter.

Working example

```
public class TowersOfHanoi extends JPanel {

    private int clock = 0;
    private Color circles = new Color(176, 56, 251);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Print the shapes and frame
        TowersOfHanoi drawRectangle = new TowersOfHanoi();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Towers of Hanoi");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawRectangle);
        frame.setSize(1250, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                drawRectangle.nextFrame();
                drawRectangle.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void nextFrame() {
        clock++;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        frame1(g);
        if (clock >= 1) {
            frame2(g);
        }
        if (clock >= 2) {
            frame3(g);
        }
    }

    private Color frame1(Graphics g) {
        Color pegs = new Color(251, 129, 56);
        g.setColor(pegs);

        // peg 1
        g.fillRect(250, 300, 25, 450);
        // peg 2
        g.fillRect(600, 300, 25, 450);
        // peg 3
        g.fillRect(950, 300, 25, 450);
        // bottom
        g.fillRect(200, 700, 825, 50);
        // create a color for circles
        // cirle 7 (Labeled from bottom to top)
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(60, 640, 400, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(60, 640, 400, 60);
        return circles;
    }

    private void frame2(Graphics g) {
        // circle 6
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(85, 580, 350, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(85, 580, 350, 60);
    }

    private void frame3(Graphics g) {
        // circle 5
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(110, 520, 300, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(110, 520, 300, 60);
        // circle 4
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(135, 465, 250, 55);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(135, 465, 250, 55);
        // circle 3
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(160, 420, 200, 45);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(160, 420, 200, 45);
        // circle 2
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(185, 380, 150, 40);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(185, 380, 150, 40);
        // circle 1
        g.setColor(circles);
        g.fillOval(210, 345, 100, 35);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(210, 345, 100, 35);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How can I clear a shape after it has been drawn? Is there a "delete" function to erase it from the screen other than clearRect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Caldender()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`? If you do, you can get the current time. After you have gotten the time, do a `while` loop to check what the time is now. When you do `LastTime - Now`, to check how much time has passed.

This code is not tested, (But it should work).

```
long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while(true){

   long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

   if(lastTime - now == [YOUR PREFFERD WAITING TIME IN MS]){
      break;
   }
}
```

And now draw your graphics.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this on the UI/Event dispatcher thread, it would be no better than sleep

Answer (score 0):

You should probably restructure you code so that paint component draws the current state of the system of pegs and rings. Then use a Swing timer to call a method that moves the state of the system then calls repaint().